# проблема с touchCount

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Проблема в том, что иногда неверно считываются касания. Допустим на таскрине 2 пальца, а показывает 1.
Такая ситуация возникает когда касаешься двумя пальцами и расстояние между ними минимальное. Когда расстояние между двумя пальцами хоть 1 см - работает вроде норм. 
Это у меня с тачем проблема или с кодом? 
 P.S. юзаю unity remote

```
    int fingerCount = 0;
    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {

        fingerCount++;

    }

    if (fingerCount == 1)
    {
        Debug.Log("1");
        _railMover.RotatingCam();
    }
    if (fingerCount == 2)
    {
        touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        touchX += touch.deltaPosition.x * xSpeed * 0.02f;
        touchY -= touch.deltaPosition.y * ySpeed * 0.02f;
        Debug.Log("2");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, есть **Input.touchCount**, который количество *тачей* сообщает.
Во-вторых, у самого устройства как и у программы, есть ограничения(так называемые **Threshold**), это минимальное расстояние между двумя *тачами*, если расстояние меньше этого минимального, то система считает, что это один *тач*. Во многом, еще зависит от типа экрана(по гуглите, различные типы экранов и как они работают).

p.s. То что у вас 1 см между пальцами, конечно, странно... Что за устройство у вас такое?

Comment: nexus 4) да, пробовал через  Input.touchCount, но результат такой же. Поэтому скопипастил код со справки юнити.

Comment: когда расстояние меньше 1 см тоже работает) но редко)